# Multiple line graphs using plotly in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly

I'm new to shiny R and Plotly. I'm trying to build a dashboard that has two drop-down boxes and we take input through these dropdown boxes and plot Plotly graphs. All the datasets have time, temp, and weight columns. time goes on the x-axis and for y-axis we can select either temp or weight or maybe both.

1. the first drop-down takes the input to which dataset to select.
2. second dropdown box takes the input to select the variable from the dataset selected.
   Most of the things I have figured out, however, y-axis label does not change dynamically. the label is getting (input$variable) instead of temp or weight.

[here is the shiny r output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehjIE.png)
also here is the reproducible example and my code

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(DT)

df1 <- data.frame("time" = 1:10, "temp" = c(21,15,31,12,23,45,67,34,54,10), "weight" = c(10,20,30,40,65,35,68,89,100,23), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame("time" = 1:10, "temp" = c(31,65,31,22,23,45,67,54,54,45), "weight" = c(30,20,40,40,65,85,68,89,14,24), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)





    ui <- fluidPage(

            titlePanel( div(column(width = 5, h2('title here')), )),
            # Input: Selector for choosing dataset
            selectInput(inputId = "dataset",
                        label = "Choose a dataset:",
                        choices = c("df1","df2")),

            selectInput(inputId = "variable",
                        label = "Variable selection", 
                        choices = c("temp","weight"),
                        selected = "weight",
                        multiple = FALSE),
            mainPanel(
                    # Output
                    tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                                tabPanel("Plot", plotlyOutput('plot')),
                                tabPanel("Data", DT::dataTableOutput("table")),
                                tabPanel("Key_metrics", DT::dataTableOutput("Key_metrics")))
            )
    )

    server <- function(input, output) {
            dataDf <- reactive({
                    temp <- get(input$dataset)

            })

            output$plot <- renderPlotly(
                    plot_ly(dataDf(), x = ~time, y =~get(input$variable), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', name = "temp") %>%
                            add_trace(dataDf(), x = ~time, y = ~weight, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',name = "weight") 

            )

            output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
                    dataDf()
            })
            output$Key_metrics <- DT::renderDataTable({

            })

    }

    shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify axis labels in `layout()`. Note that `xaxis` and `yaxis` require a list as argument (see [here](https://plotly.com/r/axes/) for more details):

```
output$plot <- renderPlotly(
    plot_ly(dataDf(), x = ~time, y =~get(input$variable), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', name = "temp") %>%
      add_trace(dataDf(), x = ~time, y = ~weight, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',name = "weight") %>%
      layout(xaxis = list(title = "Time"), yaxis = list(title = input$variable))

)
```

**Edit:** following a comment, here's how to plot two lines if two variables are selected and one otherwise (don't forget to put `multiple = TRUE` in `selectInput()`:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(DT)

df1 <- data.frame("time" = 1:10, "temp" = c(21,15,31,12,23,45,67,34,54,10), "weight" = c(10,20,30,40,65,35,68,89,100,23), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame("time" = 1:10, "temp" = c(31,65,31,22,23,45,67,54,54,45), "weight" = c(30,20,40,40,65,85,68,89,14,24), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)



ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel( div(column(width = 5, h2('title here')), )),
  # Input: Selector for choosing dataset
  selectInput(inputId = "dataset",
              label = "Choose a dataset:",
              choices = c("df1","df2")),

  selectInput(inputId = "variable",
              label = "Variable selection", 
              choices = c("temp","weight"),
              selected = "weight",
              multiple = TRUE),
  mainPanel(
    # Output
    tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                tabPanel("Plot", plotlyOutput('plot')),
                tabPanel("Data", DT::dataTableOutput("table")),
                tabPanel("Key_metrics", DT::dataTableOutput("Key_metrics")))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  dataDf <- reactive({
    temp <- get(input$dataset)

  })

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({

    if (length(input$variable) > 1){
      plot_ly(dataDf(), x = ~time, y =~get(input$variable[1]), 
              type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', name = "temp") %>%
        add_trace(dataDf(), x = ~time, y = ~get(input$variable[2]), 
                  type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',name = "weight") %>%
        layout(xaxis = list(title = "Time"))
    }
    else {
      plot_ly(dataDf(), x = ~time, y =~get(input$variable[1]), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', name = "temp") %>%
        add_trace(dataDf(), x = ~time, y = ~get(input$variable[1]), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',name = "weight") %>%
        layout(xaxis = list(title = "Time"), yaxis = list(title = input$variable))
    }

  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    dataDf()
  })
  output$Key_metrics <- DT::renderDataTable({

  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Put what you want as y-axis label based on the original answer. Note that this answer only works if there are two choices.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It fixed the issue. however, I have a follow-up question if you can help pls. for the variable selection drop-down, I was planning to have multiple selections. so if I select temp only temp should be plotted and if I select weight only weight should be plotted. and if i select both temp and weight then both should be plotted. is there a way to do it?

Comment: The Y-axis should be "Value" instead of weight, I think

Comment: @DanielJachetta thanks for your comment. however, bretauv helped already so I could not try what you suggested.

Comment: @bretauv how would you go about changing this code if you wanted to, for example, plot weight from both DF1 and DF2 on the same plot to compare them? Looks like this code currently only allows for comparison of timeseries data if they are coming from the same data frame selection.